# Detecting Location on Android Wear Error

Tags: android, android-service, google-play-services, wear-os, android-location

I'm following this guide: 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html, and got up to the part "Request Location Updates."
I created the class that they gave, and took care of all but one error.

This is where my error is. It is associated with performing setResultCallback().

[image: Error]

The caption reads: Class 'Anonymous class derived from ResultCallback' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onResult(R)' in 'ResultCallback.'

I'm wondering why I get it. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is missing :

```
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
```

Comment: Thanks! The guides imply some prior knowledge I guess.

Comment: Nah, they just sometimes have mistakes.

Comment: Well, they keep it vague because they assume that the developer knows his stuff. And the code does not give me any results.... I'm wondering how to get this working on this file I'm working on